# Can't reference the method

Tags: c++

When I begin to learn C++ and algorithms. I want to group code in module paradigm. so I had divide the sort procedure into 3 files, as follows:

**sort.h**

```
namespace sort
{
    void insertSort(int* a,int size);    
}
```

**sort.cpp**

```
#include "sort.h"
namespace sort
{
}
void sort::insertSort(int* a,int size)
{
    int i,j,key;
    for(j=1;j<size;j++)
    {
        key=a[j];
        i=j-1;
        while(i>=0 && a[i]>key)
        {
            a[i+1]=a[i];
            i=i-1;
        }
        a[i+1]=key;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include"sort.h"
int main()
{
    int a[6]={5,2,4,6,1,3};
    sort::insertSort(a,6);
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) std::cout<<a[i]<<'\t';
    return 0;
}
```

When I use Dev-C++ to compile the three files. I got the the below error information:

> [Linker Error] undefined reference to `sort::insertSort(int*, int)'

I don't know why. I think I have include the file "sort.h", so why is it also telling me that the compile can't reference to the method `sort::insertSort()`?

Comment: Put the function definition inside the braces of the namespace!

Comment: thanks for advice. but When I put the function definition inside the braces of the namespace. the problem is arising as before.

Comment: @Tai show us the build command

Comment: @Tai you haven't linked sort.cpp in command

Comment: "D:/main.cpp" -o "D:/main.exe"    
-I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include" 
-I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/" 
-I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/include/common"  
-L"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/lib/wx/gcc_lib" 
-L"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/lib" 
-L"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib"

Comment: @MrLister I completely understand and experience that myself, but my first reaction is not to post it on SO. A fresh set of eyes would have spotted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're building the entire program, make sure you're linking all the object files together.  The linker is complaining because your `main()` function is calling the `sort::insertSort` function, which has been *declared* in `sort.h`, but the *definition* for which has not been included in the program as a whole.

I don't know offhand what parameters to your particular Dev-C++ environment are required, but typically, make sure that all the `cpp` files are in the command line you send to the compiler frontend.